# Solving two equations in a creative way

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Given here are two equations.

Assuming "a" and "b" are not zero or infinity and using some creative thinking,

prove that "b" is *two times* "a".

> **7a x 3a x 5a = 10a**
>
> **13b x 5b = 15b**

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Suppose we treat "a" and "b" as

> postfix operators.

In math, a common one is

> ! for factorial.

If we set this as "a", then "b" is *two times* "a", i.e.,

> !! for [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). For any natural number "n", n!! is defined recursively as follows:
>  0!! = 1!! = 1,
>  n!! = n x (n-2)!! for n>1.

Indeed,

> 7! x 3! x 5! = 7! x 6 x 120 = 7! x 8 x 9 x 10 = 10!

and

> 13!! x 5!! = 13!! x 15 = 15!!

Comment: @DrD That answer doesn't look like a proof that b is two times a. It looks like "I assumed that b was two times a, and I have not encountered a contradiction so far". Perhaps the question could be rephrased "Fill in values for a and b such that b is two times a" rather than "Prove that b is two times a".

Comment: @Stef I was chosing between either "show" or "prove". As you can see from the answer noedene showed b is indeed two times a. Appreciate your comment.

Comment: @Stef Agreed, there is no "proof" possible without defining precisely what is allowed. Replacing "prove" by the synonym "show" doesn't change this either. It is more like, "Find "a" and "b" that work. Hint: "b" is *two times* "a"."